# Unable to start ipython with .pythonrc using virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv, ipython

I want to be able to start an ipython session with it importing some modules. On Windows this would be simple - I had a global installation of ipython and I used `.pythonrc` I think it was.

However, in Ubuntu 13 I have `ipython` installed in a virtualenv (but not installed globally).

In my `.bashrc` is:

```
alias ipy="python -c 'import IPython; IPython.terminal.ipapp.launch_new_instance()'"
```

I am wondering if it's possible to run similar startup commands in ipython. Or if that's not possible with my current setup - then what is the best way to achieve what I want in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully some combination of [PYTHONSTARTUP](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) or [IPYTHONDIR](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/config/overview.html) environment variables in your `.bashrc` can accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work using IPYTHONDIR="~" and creating an ipython profile at ~/home/nebffa/profile_default/ipython_config.py